# Laravel - Daily, Weekly, Monthly and Yearly Revenue Report

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I run a Laravel Eloquent query to retrieve daily, weekly, monthly and  yealy revenue reports.

**Table: revenue**

id  |  channel  |  amount   |  created_at

1   |   mabble  |    3400   |   9/10/12

2   |   gold    |     3400  |   8/10/12

3   |   mabble  |    4500   |   07/10/12

4   |   silver  |    3200   |   22/09/12

5   |  silver   |    3400   |   9/10/12

6   |  silver   |    790    |   22/09/12

7   |  gold     |   1000    |   9/08/12

8   |  mabble   |   9000    |   22/09/12

**Expected result** :the following is an example result not accurate

Date | channel | weekly revenue | monthly revenue | yearly revenue | Total Revenue

2/2/2017 | gold | 200 | 5400 | 3244 | 90222

Date | silver | 600 | 4300 | 983 | 10000

I want to sum the amount (revenue) as explained above, group by channel and created_at (date) perhaps. How do I write the eloquent query  and filter by date between using created_at. It should be done in the controller.

Comment: can you write an example? didn't understand the schema well

Comment: I have updated the question. What I want is to generate weekly, monthly and yearly revenue on the same view, grouped by channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have limited channel (like 5-20), then use the following code:

```
<?php
$items = Revenue::groupBy('channel')->get(['channel']);
$re = [];
foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
    $re['daily'][$value] = Revenue::where('channel',$value)->whereDate('created_at',date('Y-m-d'))->sum('amount');
    $re['weekly'][$value] = Revenue::where('channel',$value)->whereBetween('date', [
        Carbon::parse('last monday')->startOfDay(),
        Carbon::parse('next friday')->endOfDay(),
    ])->sum('amount');
    $re['monthly'][$value] = Revenue::where('channel',$value)->whereMonth('created_at',date('m'))->sum('amount');
    $re['yearly'][$value] = Revenue::where('channel',$value)->whereYear('created_at',date('Y'))->sum('amount');
}

var_dump($re);
```

In this code, we are separating channels first and then using them to calculate the required result. Btw, code is to tested.

Comment: What will be the effect if I have more than 20 channels

Comment: If you have more then 20 this will run (20*4 + 1) query, which will slow down the application.

Comment: Okay. Thanks so much